# Prevent insert statement from reordering table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am creating a foreign key table. The table will holds groupnames (as its primary key), which is referenced as a FK in the main table. Many objects in the main table might belong to one group.

There are a lot of different groupnames, so I would like to add them all at once with an insert into statement. However, I want 'None' to be the top value in the table so that its easy to click it when adding new entries in the main table.

However, when I put 'None' in the FK table, then do the insert into statement, the table reorders itself (alphabetically) automatically, putting 'None' near the middle and not easily clickable.

How can I prevent the table from reordering itself?

Edit:
Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm using the Navicat GUI to add data to the table, so when adding data to the Primary table, the foreign key field is a drop down (which has a top and a bottom, and is ordered alphabetically).

Also, I found that when any new value is added to the foreign key table, the GUI reorders it alphabetically (since there are no indexes in the foreign key table to order it by). It has nothing to do with the insert into statement.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *top value* in a table.

Comment: A table is unordered, by definition. You can impose order when retrieving data from the table by using an Order by statement.

Comment: Sounds like a question about how to design a listbox and order the entries in the desired manner.

Comment: Use an ordering column in your table - then you can sort by it. i.e. make sure "none" is 1, then "something, 2, anything 3, more codes, 4 etc

Comment: Show the query used to load the table and what YOU mean by "top value in the table".  That has no meaning in a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to return the value that you want as *top* is to use conditional sorting in your select statement:

```
select * 
from tablename
order by case when groupname = 'None' then 1 else 2 end
```

For Mysql this can be simplified to:

```
order by groupname <> 'None'
```

or:

```
order by groupname = 'None' desc
```

This will return the row with 'None' first.
Change `groupname` to the actual name of the column.